# Confusion related to the time complexity for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

This is a different problem 
Given infinite supply of coins of denominations 25, 10, 5 and 1, find the distinct number of ways to use the coins to sum up to the given value.

```
    public void getCombination(int[] coins, int sum, int start, ArrayList<Node> currentValues) {
        if(sum == 0) {
            for(Node n: currentValues) {
                System.out.print(n + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            return;
        }
        int next_denom = 1;

        switch(start) {
            case 25:
                next_denom = 10;
                break;
            case 10:
                next_denom = 5;
                break;
            case 5:
                next_denom = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                currentValues.add(new Node(1, sum));
                for(Node n: currentValues) {
                    System.out.print(n);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
                currentValues.remove(currentValues.size()-1);
                return;
        }

        for(int i=0; i*start<=sum; i++) {
            currentValues.add(new Node(start,i));
            getCombination(coins, sum-(i*start), next_denom, currentValues);
            currentValues.remove(currentValues.size()-1);
        }

    }
```

The time complexity I think is O(N^d) where N is the given sum and d is the number of coins. The recursion depth is d, so the depth of the recursion tree is at most d. At worst case at each level the number of branches from a given node will be N itself.

Comment: @m69. This is not a duplicate. It is a different algorithm

Comment: `This is a different problem` - different from _what_? (I do remember the cross-reference to [What is the time complexity of this algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38948769/3789665) [to print factorisations of a given natural number].)

Comment: @greybear. Different problem compared to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948769/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-this-algorithm. It does ask for time complexity but not for the same algorithm different one.

Comment: @greybeard. What do you mean by full stop?